# Why won't this basic one-to-one relationship work in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, relationship

I'm having an issue getting a simple one-to-one relationship to work in Ember.js. I have an Article model and an Author model. However, I'm unable to display the related author information next to each article. [JS Bin of the issue](http://jsbin.com/mesunipafogu/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of issues.

First, in your template you are trying to iterate over a collection of authors even though you are defining a one-to-one relationship.  You can remove the `{{#each}}` and just have `<em>by {{ author.name }}</em>`.

Second, your Article model is not loading the associated Author record.  This can be fixed by updating the `author` relationship in `App.Article` to `author: DS.belongsTo('author', {async: true})`.  This will make an async request for the author data for each article.

[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mesunipafogu/4/)